# How to do a server call to Deezer APIs using the access token of a free user

Tags: api, deezer

something like this

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://api.deezer.com/2.0/artist/27/top?access_token=.....');
```

works if the access_token belongs to a premium user, otherwise it doesn't work. When I say it doesn't work it means that taccess_token is not considered, so for example the country of the user is not token into consideration and if the code run on a US server, the above call just gives an empty answer (because no song is allowed).

Months ago the deezer team told me that they were close to modify this in order to correctly pass the access token also for free users, but I have just tried and the issue is still there.

Is there any workaround (apart from calling the API via javascript)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an additional note: do anyone knows when this issue will be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that issue, to make things clear:

- Requests coming from US servers will receive empty data, because Deezer's not available there,
- You can work around that issue by passing an access_token parameter with the request. If the access_token is associated with a Premium user who registered in a Deezer live country (e.g. Italy for example), the request will take the user country associated with the token into account. Therefore, it will return results.
- That above workaround isn't working for free users.

This is a widely known issue and we are working on another workaround right now.

Comment: Ok, that is what I said; do you know when this issue will be fixed? As far as I know it was supposed to be fixed time ago so I'm trying to understand if there is an actual roadmap for that.

Comment: There is but not for allowing using the free user token. As I said, another solution is currrently under development and will ship shortly.